# ¿Cómo crear nuevas columnas en un dataframe usando valores de otro dataframe?

Tags: r

Tengo un dataframe con 3 columnas

```
 > df
ProyectoID                         Nombre Contratado
1    D0000052 D.O.Línea Alta Velocidad Vitor 3606443.81
2    X0000100 AT Conservación Red Foral Bizk 2218057.00
3    D0000062 D.O. Alta velocidad Hernialde- 1545665.21
4    CABL2016 Proyectos y D.O. de Abastecimi 1160413.00
5    X0000120 Bloque proyectos y obras STI 2 1063783.11
```

y otro con una sola columna

```
> df2
Años
1  2007
2  2008
3  2009
4  2010
```

Y lo que quiero es añadir en df una nueva columna por cada valor de df2 así que dentro de este bucle

```
for (variable in df2) {
 .....
}
```

estoy intetando arias opciones y ninguna me funciona

si intento esto:

```
df$variable=0
```

o esto:

```
df<-df%>%mutate(variable=0)
```

me crea esto, es decir, me crea la nueva columna con el nomre "variable" no el valor

```
df
ProyectoID                         Nombre Contratado variable
1    D0000052 D.O.Línea Alta Velocidad Vitor 3606443.81        0
2    X0000100 AT Conservación Red Foral Bizk 2218057.00        0
3    D0000062 D.O. Alta velocidad Hernialde- 1545665.21        0
4    CABL2016 Proyectos y D.O. de Abastecimi 1160413.00        0
```

he probado esto y me da error

```
for (indice in 1:nrow(df2)) {
 df$df2[indice,]=0
 df<-df%>%mutate(df2[indice,]=0)
 df<-df%>%mutate(as.character(df2[indice,])=0)
}
```

Alguna idea por favor?

Necesito algo como esto:

```
 ProyectoID                         Nombre Contratado 2007 2008 2009 2010  
1    D0000052 D.O.Línea Alta Velocidad Vitor 3606443.81    0    0    0        
2    X0000100 AT Conservación Red Foral Bizk 2218057.00    0    0    0
```

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta es esta:

```
df[as.character(df2$Años)] <-0
```